# Bootstrap .row getting out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I was studing Bootstrap grid system, so i made a row with some images, but when i reduce de resolution of the screen, my images are going below the container.

```
<div class="container main" id="second-box">

<h2 class="font-montserrat text-center"> Projects <i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i>
</h2>
<div>
  <div class="row">
      <img src= "http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded col-md-4">
      <img src= "http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded col-md-4">
      <img src= "http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded col-md-4">
      <img src= "http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded col-md-4">
  </div>
</div> </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#second-box{
   margin: 1px auto;
   height: 700px;
}
.main {
  background-color: #e0f0e2;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.projects-img{
  width: 360px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

Images:

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncB0P.png)

[Getting out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JDgC.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what is happening and maybe what you expected to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**. I propose the following solution:

```css
#second-box {
  margin: 1px auto;
}
.main {
  background-color: #e0f0e2;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.projects-img {
  width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container main" id="second-box">

  <h2 class="font-montserrat text-center"> Projects <i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i></h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Can I remove `height: 700px;`? `Try this:

```css
#second-box {
  margin: 1px auto;
}
.main {
  background-color: #e0f0e2;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.projects-img {
  width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container main" id="second-box">

  <h2 class="font-montserrat text-center"> Projects <i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i></h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg " class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg " class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MateusLuiz Why did you add 'height: 700px` ?

Comment: I was trying in various ways to fix that, but I think it was to adjust the image.

Comment: @MateusLuiz I propose one more solution.I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `col` classes inside row class. Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src= "http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src= "http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src= "http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src= "http://jackson.armylive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/05/StandBy.jpg" class="projects-img img-responsive img-rounded">
    </div>
</div>

.projects-img {
    width: 100%; //try this to make it responsive
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
```

Take a look at the documentation for more information: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: The images already have a col- class... no extra col-can-12 should be needed.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Didn't see the images you added.

Comment: A little, but when I decrease the resolution, the images are out of the container again

Comment: The problem is not in the container? It was not for him to increase height?

Comment: Can you provide the css for img-responsive class?

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was in the container, changed the height to 100%

Answer (score 0):

You're giving your images a set width of 360px in the CSS... that way they cannot become responsive and will bust out of their container...